# Weird Blocked thread warnings

Tags: vert.x

We are running a spring boot vertx application in an OpenShift cluster.
Using vertx 4.2.3 and spring boot 2.6.2.
The application listens for incoming tcp connections and forward messages to rabbit mq
We have lowered the time limit for warning about blocked thread to 500 ms

We are getting a number of warnings like this

```
Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 1250 ms, time limit is 500 ms
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.base@17.0.1/sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.1/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:118)
    at java.base@17.0.1/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:129)
    at java.base@17.0.1/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:817)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base@17.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

As this doesn't include any of our code in the stack trace. we have a hard time understanding what is wrong. We are with ZGC garbage collector and do not see any unusual GC pause times.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. What is a spring boot vertx application? 
2. Is your rabbit mq client async?
3. Have you added proper exception/failure handlers?

Comment: 1. The application is a spring boot application. We deploy verticles on startup.

2. Yes, we use async rabbitmq client, io.vertx.rabbitmq.RabbitMQClient

3. I do think we have? We see these errors once or twice a day.

Comment: Paste a code snippet and I can check

Comment: Sadly, the code is part of a larger commercial project, so I cannot do that. And I don't have a simple reproducer. 
I am just very confused about how this code is ending up running on the vertx thread - it has none of our code in the stacktrace? All our code is in a com.foo namespace.

Answer (score 0):

> Thread xyz has been blocked for

This occurs when the event loop thread has been blocked for longer than expected.

Sometimes, async clients just provide asynchronous results with an underlying synchronous executions. I would recommend checking the RabbitMq methods in usage. For example for [basicPublishWithDeliveryTag](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/rabbitmq/RabbitMQClient.html), the doc says

> Parameters:
> deliveryTagHandler - callback to capture the deliveryTag
> for this message. Note that this will be called ***synchronously*** in the
> context of the client.

Comment: Thanks.  I am aware when the message is logged. 
But I am very confused about how this code ended up running on the vertx thread - as you see, there is none of our code in the stack. 

We are using the following rabbitMq methods:
addConnectionEstablishedCallback, basicAck, basicConsumer, basicNack, basicPublish, basicQos, exchangeDeclare, isConnected, isOpenChannel, queueBind, queueDeclare, start

Comment: Do you have worker verticles running?

Comment: No, we don't. We are using vertx.createNetServer(netServerOptions) and setting up                 connectHandler and exceptionHandler on that.